# How does the internet make sure that only entities who own an IP address can rout it to themselves?

Tags: networking, ip

When companies want to advertise to the internet that packets meant for a specific IP address should be routed to them, I'm assuming they use BGP, though I only have a vague notion of how BGP works (Kind of like the Dijkstra search algorithm), but what keeps a random Joe from telling the world that packets for 8.8.8.8 should be routed to them, for example?

Comment: This actually has happened, on a national level.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/710129/can-you-grab-any-ip-address-on-the-internet is not _quite_ a duplicate, but still has good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory: BGP filters based on information from routing registries (the IRR), as well as cryptographic verification based on RPKI.

In practice: nothing much.

Good ISPs *do* filter what prefixes a customer may advertise (though often the filters are built manually), but hijacks, both accidental and malicious, still pop up in the news every so often. There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGP_hijacking) about it.

(Though I would assume sometimes it doesn't work purely because the legitimate paths end up being shorter (and therefore more preferred) than the false ones. I may be wrong.)

And of course, in order to use BGP you need to already own an AS-number and have peering arrangements with some ISP, so that alone raises the bar from "average Fred" to someone who has signed a few contracts – hopefully not under a false name, too.